# Play 2 videos from url one after another

Tags: iphone, url, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my application i want to play 2 url videos one after another.

This is my code:

`- (void)viewDidLoad {

```
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self movieURL]];

[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                        selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                          object:player];
[player play];
```

[super vieDidLoad];
}

```
- (NSURL *)movieURL {

return [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/adplayer/colgate.mp4"];//First video url after this video complete.I want to play the next url video.
```

}

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {

NSLog(@"movieFinishedCallback");
player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];    
[player autorelease];
```

}

`

After one url video completed i want to play the next url video.

please anyone help me.

I have store the url's in array like this,

```
array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/adplayer/colgate.mp4",@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/ventuno-platform-flv-sep2010/happy_family.mp4",nil];
```

Then how can i retrive the url in - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {

}method.please give me guidance in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I a have not tested it, but is should work, You might need it modify it little bit. At least, you now have an idea, how this can be done

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{ 
     [self initializPlayer];
}



static int i;   
-(void)initializPlayer
{
    if(i<=[arrMovieURL count])
        i +=1;
    else {
        i = 0;
    }

    if(player)
    {
        [player release];
        player = nil;
    }
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[arrMovieURL objectAtIndex:i]];

    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:player];

    [player play];
}


- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {

NSLog(@"movieFinishedCallback");
player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];    

 //calling again to play the next video
  [self initializPlayer];
 }
```

Comment: @Harinder:how to store url's in an array.and how can i retrive the url's one by one.please give me a sample code.please save my life.Thank you

Comment: @Harinder:I have edited my question.please kindly refer that and guide me

Comment: Not to sound too condescending, but your question actually has nothing to do with playing movies but is instead a very basic Objective-C / Foundation framework question.  I suggest picking up an introductory book on Objective-C programming.

Comment: @Mark Probst:i'm very new to iphone application.please guide me.how can retrive the url for playing video one by one in - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification method this method

Comment: No error.console message:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3040'